# Count number of ways for choosing two numbers in efficient algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I solved this problem but I got TLE **Time Limit Exceed** on online judge

the output of program is right but i think the way can be improved to be more efficient!

**the problem :**

Given `n` integer numbers, count the number of ways in which we can choose two elements such
that their absolute difference is less than `32`.

In a more formal way, count the number of pairs `(i, j) (1 ≤ i < j ≤ n)` such that

`|V[i] - V[j]| < 32`. `|X|`
is the absolute value of `X`.

**Input**

The first line of input contains one integer `T`, the number of test cases `(1 ≤ T ≤ 128)`.

Each test case begins with an integer `n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10,000)`.

The next line contains `n` integers `(1 ≤ V[i] ≤ 10,000)`.

**Output**

For each test case, print the number of pairs on a single line.

**my code in c++ :**

```
int main() {
    int T,n,i,j,k,count;
    int a[10000];
    cin>>T;

for(k=0;k<T;k++)
 {   count=0;
     cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
          if(i!=j)
          {
            if(abs(a[i]-a[j])<32)
                count++;
          }
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}
```

I need help how can I solve it in more efficient algorithm ?

Comment: i think sorting the input will help. Then you wont have to do O(n^2) every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite my previous (silly) answer, there is no need to sort the data at all. Instead you should count the frequencies of the numbers.

Then all you need to do is keep track of the number of viable numbers to pair with, while iterating over the possible values. Sorry no c++ but java should be readable as well:

```
int solve (int[] numbers) {                                                 
    int[] frequencies = new int[10001];                                     
    for (int i : numbers) frequencies[i]++;                                 
    int solution = 0;                                                       
    int inRange = 0;                                                        
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {                          
        if (i > 32) inRange -= frequencies[i - 32];                         
        solution += frequencies[i] * inRange;                               
        solution += frequencies[i] * (frequencies[i] - 1) / 2;              
        inRange += frequencies[i];                                           
    }                                                                        
    return solution;                                                         
}
```

Comment: your idea is right frequency array is the best way 

but your code output isnt right

Comment: On exactly what input do you think my code fails? Because everything I tested - including the examples provided in your link - seem to give the correct result.

Comment: sorry Stef I was wrong your solution worked perfectly Can you explain your algorithm in more detailed to be reference to every one.

Comment: can you explain line of codes from this loop to the end `for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int a[10010];
int N;
int search (int x){
int low = 0;
int high = N;
while (low < high)
{
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if (a[mid] >= x) high = mid;
    else low = mid+1;
}
return low;
}

int main() {
    cin >> N;
    for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++) cin >> a[i];
    sort(a,a+N);
    long long ans = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    {
        int t = search(a[i]+32);
        ans += (t -i - 1);
    }

    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the numbers, and then use a sliding window. Starting with the smallest number, populate a `std::deque` with the numbers so long as they are no larger than the smallest number + 31. Then in an outer loop for each number, update the sliding window and add the new size of the sliding window to the counter. Update of the sliding window can be performed in an inner loop, by first `pop_front` every number that is smaller than the current number of the outer loop, then `push_back` every number that is not larger than the current number of the outer loop + 31.

Comment: also you can solve it in frequency array or in binary search

Answer (score 1):

One faster solution would be to first sort the array, then iterate through the sorted array and for each element only visit the elements to the right of it until the difference exceeds 31.

Sorting can probably be done via count sort (since you have 1 ≤ V[i] ≤ 10,000). So you get linear time for the sorting part. It might not be necessary though (maybe quicksort suffices in order to get all the points).

Also, you can do a trick for the inner loop (the "going to the right of the current element" part). Keep in mind that if S[i+k]-S[i]<32, then S[i+k]-S[i+1]<32, where S is the sorted version of V. With this trick the whole algorithm turns linear.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done constant number of passes over the data, and actually can be done without being affected by the value of the "interval" (in your case, 32).
This is done by populating an array where `a[i] = a[i-1] + number_of_times_i_appears_in_the_data` - informally, `a[i]` holds the total number of elements that are smaller/equals to `i`.

Code (for a single test case):

```
static int UPPER_LIMIT = 10001;
static int K = 32;
int frequencies[UPPER_LIMIT] = {0}; // O(U)
int n;
std::cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // O(n)
 int x;
 std::cin >> x;
 frequencies[x] += 1;
}
for (int i = 1; i < UPPER_LIMIT; i++) { // O(U)
    frequencies[i] += frequencies[i-1];
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < UPPER_LIMIT; i++) { // O(U)
  int low_idx = std::max(i-32, 0);
  int number_of_elements_with_value_i = frequencies[i] - frequencies[i-1];
  if (number_of_elements_with_value_i == 0) continue;
  int number_of_elements_with_value_K_close_to_i =
      (frequencies[i-1] - frequencies[low_idx]);
  std::cout << "i: " << i << " number_of_elements_with_value_i: " << number_of_elements_with_value_i << " number_of_elements_with_value_K_close_to_i: " << number_of_elements_with_value_K_close_to_i << std::endl;
  count += number_of_elements_with_value_i * number_of_elements_with_value_K_close_to_i;
  // Finally, add "duplicates" of i, this is basically sum of arithmetic 
  // progression with d=1, a0=0, n=number_of_elements_with_value_i
  count += number_of_elements_with_value_i * (number_of_elements_with_value_i-1) /2;
}
std::cout << count;
```

Working full example on [IDEone](http://ideone.com/4PUR1I).

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be considered O(N) to process N input numbers and constant in time to process the input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void solve()
{
    int a[10001] = {0}, N, n, X32 = 0, ret = 0;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        cin >> n;
        a[n]++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10001; ++i)
    {
        if (i >= 32)
            X32 -= a[i-32];
        if (a[i])
        {
            ret += a[i] * X32;
            ret += a[i] * (a[i]-1)/2;
            X32 += a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << ret << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    for (int i=0 ; i<T ; i++)
        solve();
}
```

[run this code on ideone](https://ideone.com/JNxKmQ)

Solution explanation: `a[i]` represents how many times `i` was in the input series.
Then you go over entire array and X32 keeps track of number of elements that's withing range from `i`. The only tricky part really is to calculate properly when some i is repeated multiple times: `a[i] * (a[i]-1)/2`. That's it.

Comment: @MohammadOghli does this solution return expected results?

Comment: how is this O(1)? it has a loop from 0 to N-1

Comment: I think you are right, there is O(N) to process N input numbers. I updated the answer. I don't think reverse loop affect complexity in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and then use break to end loop when ever the range goes out.

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){
        int n,c=0;
        cin>>n;

        int ar[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>ar[i];

        sort(ar,ar+n);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                if(ar[j]-ar[i] < 32)
                    c++;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
}
```

Or, you can use a hash array for the range and mark occurrence of each element and then loop around and check for each element i.e. if x = 32 - y is present or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it return Time limit Exceeded because its complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

A good approach here is to split the numbers into separate buckets:

```
constexpr int limit = 10000;
constexpr int diff = 32;
constexpr int bucket_num = (limit/diff)+1;
std::array<std::vector<int>,bucket_num> buckets;

cin>>n;
int number;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> number;
    buckets[number/diff].push_back(number%diff);
}
```

Obviously the numbers that are in the same bucket are close enough to each other to fit the requirement, so we can just count all the pairs:

```
int result = std::accumulate(buckets.begin(), buckets.end(), 0,
                  [](int s, vector<int>& v){ return s + (v.size()*(v.size()-1))/2; });
```

The numbers that are in non-adjacent buckets cannot form any acceptable pairs, so we can just ignore them.

This leaves the last corner case - adjacent buckets - which can be solved in many ways:

```
for(int i=0;i<bucket_num-1;i++)
   if(buckets[i].size() && buckets[i+1].size())
      result += adjacent_buckets(buckets[i], buckets[i+1]);
```

Personally I like the "occurrence frequency" approach on the one bucket scale, but there may be better options:

```
int adjacent_buckets(const vector<int>& bucket1, const vector<int>& bucket2)
{
    std::array<int,diff> pairs{};
    for(int number : bucket1)
     {
         for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
            pairs[i]++;
     }

    return std::accumulate(bucket2.begin(), bucket2.end(), 0,
                           [&pairs](int s, int n){ return s + pairs[n]; }); 
}
```

This function first builds an array of "numbers from lower bucket that are close enough to `i`", and then sums the values from that array corresponding to the upper bucket numbers.

In general this approach has O(N) complexity, in the best case it will require pretty much only one pass, and overall should be fast enough.

[Working Ideone example](http://ideone.com/rUHgxL)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts also a nice solution with O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by sorting the input.

Then if your inner loop detects the distance grows above 32, you can break from it.

Comment: That would be still slow if there are many equal numbers, still O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone efforts and time to solve this problem.

I appreciated all Attempts to solve it.

After testing the answers on online judge I found the right and most efficient solution algorithm is [Stef's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703742/5169186) and [AbdullahAhmedAbdelmonem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596528/5169186) also pavel solution is right but it's exactly same as Stef solution in different language C++.

Stef's code got time execution **358 ms** in codeforces online judge and accepted.

also AbdullahAhmedAbdelmonem's code got time execution **421 ms** in codeforces online judge and accepted.

if they put detailed explanation to there algorithm the bounty will be to one of them.

you can try your solution and submit it to codeforces online judge at this link after choosing problem [E. Time Limit Exceeded?](http://codeforces.com/gym/100676/submit)

also I found a great algorithm solution and more understandable using frequency array and it's complexity O(n).

in this algorithm you only need to take specific range for each inserted element to the array which is:

```
begin = element - 32  
end = element + 32
```

and then count number of pair in this range for each inserted element in the frequency array :

```
int main() {
    int T,n,i,j,k,b,e,count;
    int v[10000];
    int freq[10001];

    cin>>T;   
 for(k=0;k<T;k++)
 { 
    count=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=10000;i++)
    {
      freq[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     cin>>v[i];
    }   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     count=count+freq[v[i]];

     b=v[i]-31;
     e=v[i]+31;

     if(b<=0)
         b=1;
     if(e>10000)
        e=10000;

     for(j=b;j<=e;j++)
      {
        freq[j]++;
      }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}
```

finally i think the best approach to solve this kind of problems to use frequency array and count number of pairs in specific range because it's time complexity is O(n).